# Spring ModelAndView set request header values

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, request

Is there any way to set some header values for spring ModelAndView. The exact issue is the following.

```
final String confirmationUrl = details.getConfirmationUrl() + details.getOrderAttemptUuid();
final ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(confirmationUrl));
```

I am creating a new model and view, but would like to set the referer header to some specific value. Is there any way of doing this?

The reason is that when i am comming from https pages and redirecting to https the referer is kept in the request, but when I am comming from https but redirecting to http I lost the referer as per

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3

Is there any way to keep the referer in the request or set it back to the ModelAndView?

Answer (score -2):

Consider maybe returning a ResponseEntity from your request mapping.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html

Then you can set response headers using like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/handle")  public ResponseEntity<String> handle() { 
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();   
    responseHeaders.set("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't show how to return a model and view, it only returns a string.

Answer (score -3):

Could you use the addObject(name, value) method on ModelAndView to store?

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html